# How to achieve a BW negative in ruby-vips

Tags: ruby, vips

I have a png with the outline of an irregularly shaped object which I want to turn into a mask. I need to floodfill the interior with black, and then swap black and white. It's 8-bit grayscale, with values of 0 and 255 only.

[image]

I can't fill the exterior, leaving the interior white, since the outline itself must be included in the positive area. (Assume the array values for black, white, and red are already defined.)

```
    mask =  Vips::Image.new_from_file(fl)
    mask = mask.draw_flood(black, center_x, center_y, :equal => true) * -1
```

This returns an all-black raster. Boo hoo! This works, but is ugly and inefficient.

```
    mask = mask.draw_flood(black, center_x, center_y, :equal => true)
    mask = mask.draw_flood(red, 0, 0, :equal => true)
    mask = mask.draw_flood(white, center_x, center_y, :equal => true)
    mask = mask.draw_flood(black, 0, 0, :equal => true)
```

Does anyone know a more elegant solution? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it, it's the `* -1` that's messing you up. That'll make a float image with each pixel * -1 (obviously), so your white areas will become -255. When you save as PNG again, the image will be cast back to uint8, the negatives will be chopped off and you'll just see zero.

You really want `255 - x`, but Ruby won't let you have a number on the left of a binary image operator, so you need to write `x * -1 + 255`.

You can go one better: ruby-vips has `#invert`, which calculates (image-format-max - image-pixel) and doesn't change the numeric format. In this case that means (255 - x) and staying as uint8.

So this:

```
x = Vips::Image.new_from_file "flood1.png"
x = x.draw_flood 0, 256, 256, equal: true
x = x.invert
x.write_to_file "x.png"
```

Makes this:

[image]

(the edges are all screwy -- your example was anti-aliased by the time I got it, sorry)

Comment: Thanks a lot, user894763! This worked like a charm. In this project I've used convert, Imagemagick, rmagick, vips, and java, both raw and Graph2D. Up until two weeks ago, I had no knowledge of any of them, and it's a lot of documentation to get through. A lot of picking and choosing, like a cafeteria. Wouldn't it be great if their raster classes were interoperable?

Comment: Wow, that's quite a smorgasbord of software. libvips is the best, obviously, hehe. I do medical imaging and there packages often don't even interoperate at the file format level :( DICOM has as many flavours as there are scanner manufacturers.